# TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable inside while loop

Tags: python, dataframe, while-loop

I have developed below while loop and need to print an element in the data frame

```
row=0
row1=0
while row < len(Exmil_df):
    while row1 < len(Schedule_df):
        print(row1['Qty'])
        row1['Allocation']=0
        row['left_qty']=row['Qty']
```

I am getting this error.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-30-93e354c324e6> in <module>
      3 while row < len(Exmil_df):
      4     while row1 < len(Schedule_df):
----> 5         print(row1['Qty'])
      6         row1['Allocation']=0
      7         row['left_qty']=row['Qty']

TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: That 100% normal, you defined `row1=0` then do `row1['Qty']`, what did you expect ?

Comment: What are you trying to do ? can you add more details and be more specific

Comment: `row` and `row1` are integers.  So you can't index into them.  Think about it.  The first time through, `row1['Qty']` is equivalent to `0['Qty']`, which is gibberish.

Comment: try naming the variable "row_number = 0" so you better understand why you can't use it that way. Then maybe row = queryset[row_number] inside the loop. Actually we could do better, but this isn't a tutorial -- I'm just answering the one question.

Comment: @azro I  need to print the 'Qty' column of 'Schedule_df ' data frame.Here I am reffering to index by 'row1'. Don't I need to assign the index to 0 when running the while loop from begining?

Comment: @TomKarzes Understood the problem. But how can I print elements inside the for loop? Don't I need to use index?

Comment: If you need to print Qty from Schedule_df, then you should just do that, instead of printing the Qty from some random integer. Just because you named it "row" doesn't make it actually a row.

Comment: You can iterate over the rows directly: `for row in Exmil_df: for row1 in Schedule_df: ...`.

Comment: @KennyOstrom ,@chepner  But print(Schedule_df['Qty']) will print the entire column. Can I have the to print only one record, literally the first record?